# Kerberos user authentication in Apache

Tags: apache, authentication, kerberos

can anybody recommend some really good resources for how to get Apache authenticating users with Kerberos.

Background reading on Kerberos would also be useful

Thanks

Peter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

mod_auth_kerb is a good start: http://modauthkerb.sourceforge.net/. If you need Active Directory support, look here: http://support.microsoft.com/?id=555092.

Answer (score 1):

I found mod_auth_spnego also quite okay, as it can use SSPI on windows instead of requiring MIT Kerberos. [mod_spnego](http://sourceforge.net/projects/modgssapache/)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using Active Directory as the KDC:
http://oslabs.mikro-net.com/krb_apache.html

Answer (score 1):

I liked this article about configuring apache to use Kerberos:

http://www.roguelynn.com/words/apache-kerberos-for-django/

(you may skip parts about django if you are not interested)

EDIT:

**Fullblown answer**

It is pretty easy to configure apache to use Kerberos authentication.

I am assuming you have correctly configured Kerberos on your machine.

1) Your webserver has to have keytab [1].

Bottom line, your webserver *has* to be able to read the keytab!

2) You have to have proper httpd module for authentication -- `mod_auth_kerb`:

```
LoadModule auth_kerb_module modules/mod_auth_kerb.so
```

3) Then you have to tell apache about Kerberos:

```
<Location /> 
    AuthName "Kerberos Authentication -- this will be showed to users via BasicAuth"
    AuthType Kerberos
    KrbMethodNegotiate On
    KrbMethodK5Passwd Off
    # this is the principal from your keytab (you may lose the FQDN part)
    KrbServiceName HTTP/$FQDN
    KrbAuthRealms KERBEROS_DOMAIN
    Krb5KeyTab /path/to/http.keytab
    Require valid-user

    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
</Location>
```

Then apache will pass the user to your app via `REMOTE_USER` HTTP header.

And that's it.

I also advice you to turn on debugging logging in apache during setup. Be sure that you have correct time and httpd can read keytab, that's all.

[1] http://kb.iu.edu/data/aumh.html

[2] Main resource: http://www.roguelynn.com/words/apache-kerberos-for-django/

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please note that you should post the essential parts of the answer here, on this site, or your post risks being deleted [See the FAQ where it mentions answers that are 'barely more than a link'.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) You may still include the link if you wish, but only as a 'reference'. The answer should stand on its own without needing the link.

Comment: @bluefeet Thank you for pointing that out. As I look at the question, it states that author of the question is looking for "good resources" for "Apache authenticating users with Kerberos". Also is looking for "Background reading on Kerberos". I understand it as he/she is looking for some articles, tutorials, books or blog posts about how Kerberos works or how to set it up. And that's exactly what my answer contains. I know that it violates the rule you have mentioned but what if it's (maybe) proper answer for the question. But I guess I could improve it.